# System Image: Google APIs VS Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор

Когда обновляешь SDK / API для Android, то при скачивании образа телефона на эмулятор есть несколько вариантов:

1. Intel x86
2. Google APIs Intel x86
3. Google PLAY Intel x86

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании эмулятора, Google PLAY Intel x86 можно поставить лишь на те телефоны, где есть значок для них. Для телефонов, где нет этого значка, надо скачивать Google APIs Intel x86.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросы:

1. В чем разница между этими 3-мя образами?
2. Чем отличаются Atom от Atom_64?
3. Какой образ лучше использовать для эмулятора?